# In Kbase database, What syntax is the same as "in" in Mysql

Tags: database

In Kbase database, Is there a syntax can reach to the same effect just like "in" in Mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kbase database, it uses "+" instead of "in" in Mysql.

```
For example : where feildName = value1 + value2 + value3......
```

Comment: Great,it help me a lot.

Comment: Great，could help you!